# read.csv from list to get unique colnames

Tags: r, lapply

I am reading my files into `file_list`. The data is read using read.csv, however, I want the data in `datalist` to have colnames as the file-names the `file_list`. The original files does not have a header. 
How do I change `function(x)`  so that the the second column has colname similar to the file-name. The first column does not have to be unique.

```
file_list = list.files(pattern="*.csv")     

datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F,sep = "\t")})
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I change function(x) so that the the second column has colname similar to the file-name?

```
datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){
    dat = read.csv(file=x, header=F, sep = "\t")
    names(dat)[2] = x
    return(dat)
})
```

This will put the name of the file as the name of the second column. If you want to edit the name, use `gsub` or `substr` (or similar) on `x` to modify the string.

Comment: Perfect, nice solution

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another step.

`names(datalist) <- file_list`

Comment: This will switch the list names. I think OP is asking to rename the columns of the data frames in the list.

Comment: You are correct. This would set you up to get the filenames if you split the list to a dataframe using `ldply`. Your solution is the correct one for what they wanted.