# Creating a list of multiple excel files that have been converted to dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have 4 excel files in the one folder on my computer. The files contain both alphanumeric and numeric data. I want to write a function to sequentially read each xlsx file, convert it to a dataframe, then store the dataframe names in a list. This will allow me to use "lapply" with a function on each of these dataframes later on.

Any ideas?

Comment: `purrr` is a great tool to make this simple.   https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using lapply and read.csv on multiple files (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441204/using-lapply-and-read-csv-on-multiple-files-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read.csv from list to get unique colnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562784/read-csv-from-list-to-get-unique-colnames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.files()` lists all the files in a directory, use this with `lapply()` and `read_xlsx()`. In this example I set the working directory to the folder containing the files.

```
library(readxl)
files <- list.files()
dat <- lapply(files, read_xlsx)
dat

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#       a  a__1  a__2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#       b  b__1  b__2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     2     2
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#       c  c__1  c__2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     3     3     3
```